# Elasticsearch where dividing two field is bigger than

Tags: elasticsearch

Trying to make a boolean query where 'X/Y>0.60'.

Couldn't make It with no logic.

Need help for making logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [script query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html) in a filter context.
Here's an example:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "source": "doc.x.value / doc.y.value == params.foo",
            "params": {
              "foo": 0.60
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: alternatively, assuming both the `X` and `Y` values exist in the same document, use a runtime field - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/runtime.html - with a similar script